# React Native ScrollView Empty Footer (flexGrow behaviour)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, flexbox

I have the below code set so that the blue area in image 1 is not scollable when there is enough room and it becomes scrollable when there's not enough room. My issue is that the ScrollView component has added extra spacing at the bottom which is colored red. What I need is the green area to be directly below the ScrollView content (blue); the red should never exist.

How do I remove the red section from the ScrollView to make it look like image 2? The only time the ScrollView is scrollable is in image 3.

```
import { View, ScrollView, SafeAreaView, StyleSheet, Text } from 'react-native';

export default function App() {
  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
      <View style={ { flex: 1 } }>
        <ScrollView style={ { backgroundColor: "red" } } >
          <View style={{ backgroundColor: "blue"}}>
            {
              [...Array(5)].map((item, index) => {
                return (
                  <View key={index} style={{backgroundColor: index%2 == 0 ? '#34ff21' : '#55ffff', height: 50, margin: 20}}>
                    <Text style={{textAlign: 'center'}}>{index}</Text>
                  </View>
                )
              })
            }
          </View>
          
        </ScrollView>
        <View style={ [ { backgroundColor: "green"  }] }>
          <View style={ { height: 50, width: 200  } }/>
        </View>
      </View>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#ecf0f1',
    padding: 8,
  },
});
```

Expo example: https://snack.expo.dev/@c-gibson-emesent/honest-red-scones

[image: image 1]
Image 1: Current behaviour when ScrollView is not scrollable

[image: image 2]
Image 2: Expected look / behaviour when the ScrollView is not scrollable

[image: image 3]
Image 3: How it should look when the items expand the ScrollView until there's no more room and the ScrollView becomes scrollable.

Answer (score 0):

you need to wrap < ScrollView > with another <View style={{flex: 1}}>
what flex: 1 will do is it will take the remaining space.

check the below link
https://snack.expo.dev/J76HlNJvg-jFI1Ae3OgnI

Comment: Thanks for taking a look @siddesh94, I appreciate your time. That doesn't solve the issue when there are only 5 items as the ScrollView still takes up the remaining space. Please see image 2 on how it should look when there are a small number of items.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).